# WebSocket response as Promise with multiple messages problem

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, promise

I am using angularjs for a web site where I have to download data every seccond. To do that I am using a WebSocket, the problem is that I am sending a lot of different requests of different types. To elaborate the request I use Promises but some times the answers get to the wrong function. Let me make an example:

So I have a service that is making the request and gets the result as Promise.

```
socketService.$inject = [];
function socketService(){
    let service = this;

    let server = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8090');
    let isOpen = false;

    server.onopen = function(){
        isOpen = true;
    };

    server.onerror = function(){
      //TODO handle error
    };

    service.sendRequest = function(action, data){
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            if (isOpen) {
                server.send(encodeRequest(action, data));
                server.onmessage = function (message) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(message.data));
                }
            }

            server.onopen = function () {
                server.send(encodeRequest(action, data));
                server.onmessage = function(message) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(message.data));
                    isOpen = true;
                }
            };

            server.onerror = function (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        })
    };

}
```

And I use it like this:

```
socketService.sendRequest('get_events', {})
  .then(function (response) {
      //DO SOMETHING WITH THE RESPONSE
      return socketService.sendRequest('get_history', {
          fromDate: value,
          toDate  : value,
          tag     : value,
          event   : value
      })
  })
  .then(function (response) {
      //DO SOMETHING WITH THE RESPONSE
  });
```

The problem is that if I make the requests like this (when one promise is resolved I call the other it works perfectly) but if instead I do for example some requests every second and then in the same time I make a new request (`socketService.sendRequest(...)`) the results get messed up.

I figured out that the problem is that if I make a request and before I get the result of the first request I make another one, the response of the first request goes to the second one.

I don't understand why this happens because I return every time a new Promise, so it should resolve the response of that Promise instead of resolving the response of the next Promise.

I read that once a promise is resolved it cannot be used again (it returns the last result over and over) but I create a new one every time.

Can someone explain to me what happens and how I could fix this?

Comment: Since you are using one instance of websocket and sending parallel(async) requests, there is no garantee that messages will be resolved in input order. You should serialize all requests or create multiple instances on different ws addresses..

Comment: Another issue is that `server.onmessage` can only take a single callback. When you change it, you actually replace the old one. Pretty sure you can use [socket.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Example) though. And as @bigless said, you might want to serialize, or add a unique identifier to each request which comes back with your response, so that you can match them up.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers! I think I'll go with the multiple ws instances.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put a unique ID into the messages so that you can ensure that each response gets correlated to the correct request.  But before diving into coding this, you may want to look at json rpc 2.0.  This is a standard, with a couple of different javascript implementations, that will handle most of this for you.  I have had good luck with https://github.com/jershell/simple-jsonrpc-js

You also asked why your Promise code is not working the way you expect it to. The answer is... well, Promise doesn't work the way you expect it to.  :-)  OK, let me try to be more helpful.  Your Promise code is altering the server's callback methods (onOpen, onMessage, etc.) so that they will call the promise's "resolve" function.  The problem is that, even though you have multiple promises, you only have one server.  So each Promise you create just points the server callback methods to a new resolve function.

But... skip all that.  Someone else has already figured this out for you.  Use JSON RPC 2.0.

Duncan

Comment: Hi Duncan I already have an unique ID ( is the action parameter ) but this wont work for me because the problem is I lose messages for the reason that you already explained. Thanks for the explanation for the Promise issue, it is much more clear now why my code acts how it doses.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issues, as WebSocket message work as events. I have written one library where we can write Promise based send and receive the message.

https://github.com/pathikdevani/linka